# WWW::Mechanize Perl

Tags: perl

I am writing a simple code to login to a website for learning purpose.

I get an error saying "No Form Defined"

How do I know the form name?

Below is the code snippet (I found it from this forum).

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use WWW::Mechanize;
use HTTP::Cookies;

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
my $url = "http://www.something.net";

$mech->cookie_jar->set_cookie(0,"start",1,"/",".something.net");
$mech->get($url);
$mech->form_name("frmLogin");
$mech->set_fields(user=>'user',passwrd=>'password');
$mech->click();
$mech->save_content("logged_in.html");
```

Does the code look alright?

Comment: Yes, as stated before I got this code from someone in this forum. But I couldn't make it work. It says the "form is undefined" when I execute ! Is the form name 'frmLogin' a generic name and can be used anywhere ?

Comment: this has little to do with perl and more to do with the library / url target particulars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the form(s), if any, are embedded in the content that you are retrieving. If you view the source for this page, for example, you will find many `form` elements. This one has the id `add-comment-44827103`:

```
    <form id="add-comment-44827103" 
      class="" 
      data-placeholdertext="Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in comments."></form>
```

You can retrieve them with [`$mech->forms`](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize#$mech->forms). This call returns a list of [`HTML::Form`](http://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Form) objects that you can interrogate further.

```
my ($form) = $mech->forms;   # note ($var)=... for list context
my $form_id = $form->attr("id") || die "form on page doesn't have 'id' attr";
$mech->form_id($form_id);
...
```

There is also the `$mech->form_number( index )` call

```
$mech->form_number(2);     # select the 2nd  form  on the page
```

Comment: You're right, but the OP is asking about the form *name* which is in the `name` attribute.